# Redirecting IP with port to Domain does not work

Tags: rewrite, iis-8.5

I've read several threads on here about how to redirect an IP address to a domain. I'm currently setting up our development server inside the company network and thus we've set a "virtual" domain in the DNS of our main server.

So far all applications were installed running on *{IP}*:*{Port}*. Now I'd like to change that to the domain, since it's easier to use and read and because cookies differ for IP and domain respectively (thus preventing issues).

Obviously since I am running applications which require a specific port the redirects I've found do not work.

I tried the following settings in IIS Url Rewrite:

```
**Pattern:** {.\*}
**Condition:** {SERVER_NAME} matches *192.168.50.100*
**Action:** Redirect *Permanent* to `http://dev.myserver.de:{SERVER_PORT}/{R:1}`
```

But that does simply not work. My local browser just keeps using the IP based URL. I also tried using *rewrite* and other types of *redirect*. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `{HTTP_HOST}` as the variable to match against instead of `SERVER_NAME`. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx) suggests that `SERVER_NAME` will produce the canonical name of the box rather than what was in the host header of the request.